# Default behaviour for Object.create()

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to understand how object creation works and the corresponding prototype for an object created with `Object.create()`. I have the following code:

```
var obj = Object.create({name: "someValue"});

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); // => Object{name: "someValue"}

console.log(obj.constructor.prototype); // => Object{}

// check if obj inherits from Object.prototype
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj); // => true
```

Is it correct to assert that the last line of code returns true since the object `{name: "someValue"}` itself inherits from Object.prototype? Is there any better explanation to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification of  [`Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.6) it states that isPrototypeOf checks the chain and not just the parent:

> Repeat
>
> 1. Let V be the value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of V.
> 2. if V is null, return false
> 3. If O and V refer to the same object, return true.

Your assertion is perfectly correct. The prototype chain created is in the format:

```
obj => Object {name:"someValue"} => Object {} => null
                                      / \
                                       |
                                       \ -- This guy is Object.prototype
```

You can validated it with code by creating an object using `Object.create` and passing null as an argument.

```
var obj = Object.create(null);
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj); //false
```

Here, since we're passing `null` and not an object, it itself does not have Object.prototype as a prototype so we get `false`.

Comment: Just a note, another way to verify that indeed this is the case is by doing `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) === Object.prototype` . `Object.prototype` represents the prototype of the object called when performing `new Object()` or the more common direct literal notation.

Comment: #note-to-self The nested function invocation style used by Benjamin Gruenbaum is possible since `Object.getPrototypeOf()` returns an `object`.